# Real analysis continuity problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have encountered this problem. Can someone help me with it?

Let $f, g : [0, 1] → R$ be two continuous functions, such that $f(x) = g(x), ∀x ∈ [0, 1] ∩ Q$. Prove
that $f(x) = g(x), ∀x ∈ [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in [0,1]$. If $x$ rational, then $f(x) = g(x)$ is given. If $x$ is irrational, let $\{q_n\}$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $x$. By continuity,
\begin{align*}
f(q_n) \to f(x) \\
g(q_n) \to g(x)
\end{align*}
Since the $q_n$'s are rational, we must have
\begin{align*}
f(q_n) = g(q_n) \Rightarrow f(x) = \lim f(q_n) = \lim g(q_n) = g(x)
\end{align*}
for any $x\in [0,1]$.